# Use gravity to define downwards acceleration and velocity, overriding physics controls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, game-physics, gravity, rigid-bodies

Using Unity LTS 2020.3.0f1

```
//This works.  Notice line 27 (inputVectory = ...): I am trying to use physics.Gravity instead of -0.98F for the Y component.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Defined by B_M_N#7909
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody rb;

    private float inputX;
    private float inputY;
    //private float inputZ;
    private Vector3 inputVector;
    private float PlayerVehicleAgility;
}
    void start
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    // Below this is identical to the code in the previous post.
    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = inputVector;
        PlayerVehicleAgility = 10f;
        inputVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * PlayerVehicleAgility, -0.98F, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * PlayerVehicleAgility);

        transform.LookAt(transform.position + new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0, inputVector.z));
    }
}
```

So, what I'm trying to do, as mentioned in the comment on Line1, is have physics manage gravity instead of writing -0.98F on line 27.

I tried a few things and got error messages.  For example:

```
    inputVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * PlayerVehicleAgility, rb.Velocity.y, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * PlayerVehicleAgility); //Unexpected behavior, the car "floats" or "falls too slowly".

    inputVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * PlayerVehicleAgility, rb.Velocity.y * physics.Gravity, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * PlayerVehicleAgility); //Error: cannot multiply double by float".

    inputVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * PlayerVehicleAgility, rb.Velocity.y, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * PlayerVehicleAgility); //Error: cannot implicitly convert from UnityEngine.Vector3 to float.
```

etc.

So, at this point, I'm SOL because I don't know the manual well enough.  Thought somebody could point me to the best/standard/correct method, please?

A bit of speculation: someone told me I could individually assign AxisRaw to the X and Z direction without mentioning Y, but they couldn't show me how--I'll delete this paragraph if that's wrong-headed.

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit off with the formula to calculate the velocity from gravity. In physics it is `v=g*t`, which calculates the speed after free falling for some time.

Since you're in an update loop you can plug in`Time.delatTime` for the time, multiply it to the gravity and add all this to the previous speed:
`fall_speed = rb.velocity.y + Physics.gravity.y * Time.delatTime`

You can insert this into your previous line of code:

```csharp
inputVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * PlayerVehicleAgility, rb.velocity.y + Physics.gravity.y * Time.delatTime, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * PlayerVehicleAgility);
```

The value of gravity is 9.81f by default. In many games this feels rather slow, so it isn't uncommon to have three or five times the gravity.

Comment: Wanted to say thank you.  I need to confirm this, and I'm deployed.  It will be a while.  Just wanted to say thank you until then.